# C++ How to retrieve a file permission and ownership via win32 api

Tags: c++, file, winapi, permissions, ownership

I've been searching over the internet how to retrieve permissions and ownership of a file using win32 api, and yet I have no answer.

I'm new with the win32 api , read some guides from the internet, tried to analyze some code
associating with this api and still I'm clueless.

Could you guys help me out with some piece of advice or some directions , tips etc.

I'm sorry that I can't be more specific than that by adding some code, I don't see any reason to import any code of my own since the only remaining function is the one retrieving this information and the rest is simple(User interface and etc).

Comment: While not part of the WIN32 API, the CRT contains functions like [`_fstat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/221w8e43.aspx) that can be used to get read/write permissions.

Comment: The link in @Someprogrammerdude's comment above currently redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fstat-fstat32-fstat64-fstati64-fstat32i64-fstat64i32?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170

Answer (score 3):

See [Retrieving NTFS Permissions with C++](https://www.devx.com/c-zone/16711/). But, basically, you call [GetFileSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfilesecuritya?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get a security descriptor for the file. From that, you can get the access control list (ACL) and the owner and permissions.

Comment: Linked URLs currently redirect to https://www.devx.com/c-zone/16711/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfilesecuritya?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1):

See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/secauthz/finding-the-owner-of-a-file-object-in-c--?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which finds the owner of a file using `GetSecurityInfo` and  `LookupAccountSid` functions.

Comment: Linked URL currently redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/secauthz/finding-the-owner-of-a-file-object-in-c--?redirectedfrom=MSDN