# Full access to a folder in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, folder-access

I'm writing a function to check important settings in the program.

Among other things I would like to check if I have read and write access to a folder.

Is there any way to check this with Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to check if your application has write access to a folder is to try to create a new file and check for error code. No error means you have write access. If creation succeeded, delete the file and check for error (You may have permission to create a file, write to it but not to delete it).

If you prefer to use the more complex way, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755422/c-how-to-retrieve-a-file-permission-and-ownership-via-win32-api).

Comment: Write permission doesn't imply delete permission tho. Also access wise there's a difference between [appending and overwriting file data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants).